# Compare refcursors in plsql

Tags: plsql, sys-refcursor

Our existing procedures have been modified to improve performance. In this context we have to ensure that there is no data mismatch.How can we compare 2 refcursor s coming from different these procedures?

Answer (score 0):

you may populate the result set of both the ref cursors to a table and use any of the plsql unit testing utilities like utplsql for comparing the table output.